# How to make io_service.run(); blocking

Tags: c++, boost

I have this method that I need io_service.run(); to block the method from returning while the actual REST call is not yet done. I added a "init" value for the response body just to check.

```
RESTClient::response RESTClient::get(std::string url){
    RESTClient::response ret = {};
    ret.code = 404;
    ret.body = "init";
    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
    ctx.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none);
    //ctx.set_default_verify_paths();
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    client c(io_service, ctx, "httpbin.org", "/get", "https", ret);
    io_service.run();
    return ret; // res.body returned is init
}
```

In what way the `io_service.run()` could block the method from returning until the call is finished or timed-out?

Comment: You just construct `client`, not any call to boost asio async functions. Have you them in constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `run()` to keep running when there is no "work", you can lock the service queue using a `boost::asio::io_service::work` object:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html

The usual pattern is to use a `optional<io_service::work>` or `shared_ptr<io_service::work>` so you can just do

```
_work.reset();
```

when you want the service to return from `run()`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your answer correctly, but what I need is that the io_service.run() not to return until the REST call is done, so far from what I see the REST call is not yet finished and the run() return already

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE if you want detailed help with your code. Just use a `work` object for the duration of the request. In most setups you'd keep the `io_service` for the duration of the application though.